# Deleting text after character iif it exists for each line in txt

Tags: powershell

This is what 'dict.txt' looks like:

```
cajole/V
embarrassing/A
merge/V
stripped
```

where all but the last line have slash at the end. 
I want to get the following result and save it in a separate file:

```
cajole
embarrassing
merge
stripped
```

My attempt:

```
gc .\dict.txt | %{$_.Substring(0,$_.IndexOf('/'))} | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 'list.txt'
```

Result message:

```
Exception calling "Substring" with "2" argument(s): "Length cannot be less than
zero. Parameter name: length"
At line:1 char:19
+ gc .\dict.txt | %{$_.Substring(0,$_.IndexOf('/'))} | Out-File -Encodi ...
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to remove `/` and some character from the end of each line of your file and output to a new file:

```
Get-Content dict.txt | ForEach-Object {
  $_ -replace '/.$',''
} | Out-File list.txt -Encoding UTF8
```